# apply 1-to-group transformations in pandas - python

Tags: python, function, pandas, grouping

I have a dataframe like the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "v": [1,2,3,4], "type": ["X", "Y", "Y", "Y"]}).set_index("id")

print(df)
```

which yields:

```
   type  v
id        
a     X  1
b     Y  2
c     Y  3
d     Y  4
```

and I want to subtract the mean fromeach value **BY GROUP**. after the operation I still want to have **my SINGLE values**. in other words I want to have

```
   type  v
id        
a     X  0
b     Y  -1
c     Y  0
d     Y  1
```

so, the very useful `transform` function applied to a `groupby` object (as detailed here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) is not very useful in my case and I was wondering how to approach the problem.

this is not to say I cannot solve this problem when dealing with simple functions *(division/subtract => I can use an auxiliary dataframe resulting from a groupby and then cross the results but when dealing with more complex stuff this is no longer the case)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try this:

```
  df ['v'] =  df.groupby("type")['v'].apply(lambda x: x-x.mean())
  df

      type    v
    id          
    a     X  0.0
    b     Y -1.0
    c     Y  0.0
    d     Y  1.0



​
```

Comment: My solution seems to be faster :)

Answer (score 4):

Transform will actually get you what you want (if I understand correctly):

```
df['v'] = df['v'] - df.groupby('type')['v'].transform('mean')
```

Transform calculates the applied function by group, but broadcasts the result on the original index.

---

**Edit**: timing comparisons

```
%timeit df.groupby("type")['v'].apply(lambda x: x-x.mean())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop

%timeit df['v'] - df.groupby('type')['v'].transform('mean')
1000 loops, best of 3: 922 µs per loop
```

Comment: True indeed that the solution is faster but, Merlin's solution allows for complex functions being applied, which was the original target of the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `transform` supports complex functions, but the important thing is that future visitors to the website have two different answers, and can pick the one that suits them best :)